Azure Entra Id vs AWS Cognito
I'm looking at migrating  from AWS Cognito to Azure Entra ID.
The documentation flows are unclear on using external SAML provider when users don't exist in Azure AD, and only are added on the first login.
Does anyone know if this is possible with Azure Entra ID? In AWS Cognito it is only a few clicks to setup this flow.
Appreciate any advice.
